# How do I test the Application Controller in rspec (get request)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I want to test a get request in my application controller, my spec looks like:

```
describe "GET some_get_method" do 
     it "should work" do
       get :some_get_method
    end
  end
```

But I recieve the following error when I do this:

```
Failure/Error: get :some_get_method
     AbstractController::ActionNotFound:
       The action 'some_get_method' could not be found for ApplicationController
```

My application controller looks like:

```
def some_get_method
    vari = params[:vari]

    if !vari
      render_something
      return false
    end
    true
  end
```

In my routes I have:

```
namespace :application do
    get 'some_get_method/', :action => :some_get_method
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

It probably isn't appropriate to spec `ApplicationController` directly for functional testing, as your real interest is in the behavior of the controllers derived from it.

For unit testing the methods within `ApplicationController`, however, you could create a stub controller within the spec file (or, more appropriately, a test helper) that does nothing but expose the methods you want to test in `ApplicationController`:

```
class StubController < ApplicationController
end
```

You can now test `Stub`'s methods (really `Application`'s methods) directly without having to try and instantiate an abstract class.

**Set up routing**

If you need to test rendering, one approach might be to add a test-only route accessible to RSpec's request handlers:

```
# in config/routes.rb
unless Rails.env.production?
  namespace :stub do
    get 'some_get_method', :action => :some_get_method
  end
end

# in spec
describe "GET some_get_method" do 
  it "should work" do
     get :some_get_method
     # test
  end
end
```

Comment: So yes normally I would do this controller.send(:some_method), but since its a get method can I do that? When I do this, I get errors controller.send(:some_get_method) because I get Failure/Error: #controller.send(:some_get_method)
     RuntimeError:
       ActionController::RackDelegatio

Comment: Hmm. Is it getting hung up on the `render` call? If so, is there a chance that you're trying to render an invalid/nil/otherwise-unavailable resource anywhere in the view?

Comment: So since I'm testing the application controller, it doesn't have a view. Could that be the problem? And yes it does get hung up on the render call.

Comment: Got it. How about setting up a dev-only route for `StubController`, creating the corresponding views, and using the `get`/etc. helpers? I'll update the answer.